# While Loops Syntax Errors

Tags: javascript, while-loop

The course is asking me to form a while loop and I keep getting errors or infinite loops. What am I doing wrong?

```
var understand = true;

while(understand= true){
    console.log("I'm learning while loops!");
    understand = false;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, why did you think that `=` would behave differently in different locations? I recommend to read the MDN JavaScript Guide to learn the basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: I'm using Codeacademy to learn Javascript and it never mentioned that = and == are used differently. I just assumed they were interchangeable.

Comment: That's why it's good to learn from multiple sources.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an assignment operator (`=`) and not an equals test (`==`).

Use: `while(understand == true)`

Or simplified: `while(understand)`

**Update from comments:**

`===` means the value and the data type must be equal while `==` will attempt to convert them to the same type before comparison.

For example:

```
"3" == 3 // True (implicitly)
"3" === 3 // False because a string is not a number.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed it and helped me clear up the difference between those two.

Comment: Also, can you explain to me what === is? Is it any different?

Comment: @Tim `===` is strict comparison. While `==` will attempt to make both sides the same data type, `===` will not. so `1 == "1"` works while `1 === "1"` does not.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: I assume *"make both sides the same"* means "converting both values to the same data type".

Answer (score 3):

`=` means assignment, while `==` is comparison. So:

```
while(understand == true)
```

Also note that `while` and other branch structures, take conditions. Since this is a Boolean you can just use itself:

```
while(understand)
```

Also a note of the difference between `==` and `===` (strict comparison). The comparison `==` will attempt convert the two sides to the same data type before it compares the values. While strict comparison `===` does not, making it faster in most cases. So for example:

```
1 ==  "1"  // This is true
1 === "1" // This is false
```